# ¿Por medio de un DatePickerDialog y un TimePickerDialog puedo cambiar la hora y fecha del dispositivo movil?

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Tengo implementado un DatePickerDialog y un TimePickerDialog para seleccionar la fecha y hora que uno desee pero me gustaria saber si esa fecha que coloco puedo cambiarla en el dispotivo movil.

Comment: A que te refieres con cambiarla? si la escribes que cambie la fecha del dispositivo? o si la escribes después puedas cambiarla en el control?

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde tengo entendido no es posible alterar la fecha del dispositivo android normales (solo root)
Sin embargo es posible pedirle al usuario lo cambie manualmente mediante un `Intent`

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));
```

Para el caso de dispositivos root, puedes tomar de referencia el [post de @jek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11708781/5919347).